# mysql_num_row() error

Tags: php, mysql

This is the error that I am getting while using mysql_num_rows() function

```
Error: Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

Here is my source code:

```
$title = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE item.title LIKE % " .implode("% OR item.title LIKE % ", $data);

$title_result = mysql_query($title, $this->dbh);

echo mysql_num_rows($title_result);
```

What I am doing is creating a search for a website.  Currently I am doing 4 Select statements and then I would like to total everything found in my database from all 4 of those sql statements.  If I am thinking correctly the mysql_num_rows() returns the number of rows that was found from a Select statement.  So in theory I was thinking that I could add them together to get my total found in a search, am I correct in this thinking if not how could I add 4 different sql select statements together?

Also my test search is in the database.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MySQL statement did not execute correctly. This is just a hunch, but try again after replacing your `$title` with the following:

```
$title = 'SELECT * FROM item WHERE item.title LIKE "%'.implode('%" OR item.title LIKE "%', $data).'%"';
```

Then later, execute it as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query ($title, $this->dbh) or die (mysql_error($this->dbh));
```

Note: this is assuming you trust `$data`. If it comes from external sources (such as user-specified search), you really ought to sanitise via `mysql_real_escape_string` or prepared statements

Comment: The title you suggested works.  Thank you.  Also another quick question is can you add multiple mysql_num_rows()?  My hunch would be yes as it returns an int, but I would like to just confirm my hunch.  If My hunch is wrong how could I add multiple Select statements?

Comment: @Snader - Yup, you can add the rows that way. You might be able to do it quicker, though, with a properly crafted SQL statement. Also, if you're interested only in the number of rows, a `COUNT(*)` query would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your query failed to execute. You need to check the return value of `mysql_query` before you try `mysql_num_rows`.

```
$title_result = mysql_query($title, $this->dbh);

if($title_result)
{
echo mysql_num_rows($title_result);
}
else
{
die(mysql_error());
}
```

What actually is happening in your case is `mysql_query` is returning `false`, which is not a valid MySQL result resource and when you pass it to `mysql_num_rows` it returns the following error:

```
Error: Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

Comment: Okay that is apparently my error.  So I would assume I am not using the LIKE function correctly.  I looked all over google and can't find a good explanation.  How does the LIKE work with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot that fixed all of my problems.  I can't tell you how thankful I am cause I looked at this for about 2 hours trying to figure it out and I was beginning to get very frustrated.  :)